# tinymce: default toolbar specification

Tags: tinymce

I am using tinymce editor. I am using default toolbars. I mean I am not specifying any additional toolbars:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        height: 400,
        statusbar: false,
        menubar:false
     });
  </script>
```

However, now I want to add "font-size" and "table" toolbars to the default. Can I find somewhere specification of default toolbars?

Here is how default editor looks like:
[image]

I was trying to create toolbar option bymyself but I never get the same as in default. So I would like to find default tinymce toolbar specification and add there "table" and "fontsize"  options.

Answer (score 33):

You should have figured it out by now but for the next one finding this, this should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
         selector: "textarea",
         height: 400,
         statusbar: false,
         menubar:false,
         toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | table | fontsizeselect"
      });
</script>
```

So default one is:

```
         toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent"
```

Comment: Where to find list of available toolbar buttons?

Comment: @Antoniossss You can find the full list here https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/editor-control-identifiers/#toolbarcontrols

Answer (score 1):

For TinyMCE 5, the default toolbar configuration is:

```
toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent'
```

More about TinyMCE toolbar configuration here: https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-toolbar